# How to implement User registration settings email in my registration form

Tags: 6, emails

I have a `custom registration` field that i have in my `drupal 6` site.Once a user has been `registered` a `mail` will be send to the corresponding user with his or her `account credentials`.I have used `drupal_mail function` for this purpose.Is there any means by which i could create such a mail through the back-end. I have seen `User e-mail settings`.Is it possible to implement this `mail function` through the `back-end` rather than programatically. Is yes i would be really curious to look up on that.Hope someone might help me with this..

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Rules Module](https://drupal.org/project/rules) for this.

**Steps**:

1. Define an Event that whenever a registration is there.
2. Then Define the Action to send Mail with proper Format.

For more details about the Rules module go through README.txt of this module.

Comment: tanx for the reply @Nitesh.Rather than using a contributed module,is there any other means...?Can'y i use User e-mail settings for my purpose..???

Answer (score 1):

i think you are expecting a place where you can create a email template and then call or use the same template using Rules or code depending on action.

if you want to maintain only less templates then Rules module is the more than sufficient.

or, you have many templates, then [PET](https://drupal.org/project/pet) is the solution, where you can create N number of templates, those templates can be triggered manually or using Rules.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Contributed Module you could also go for writing a custom Module ie defining hook_mail() when a particular event go for.

```
function hook_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $account = $params['account'];
  $context = $params['context'];
  $variables = array(
  '%site_name' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal'),
  '%username' => format_username($account),
);
if ($context['hook'] == 'taxonomy') {
  $entity = $params['entity'];
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_load($entity->vid);
  $variables += array(
  '%term_name' => $entity->name,
  '%term_description' => $entity->description,
  '%term_id' => $entity->tid,
  '%vocabulary_name' => $vocabulary->name,
  '%vocabulary_description' => $vocabulary->description,
  '%vocabulary_id' => $vocabulary->vid,
 );
}

// Node-based variable translation is only available if we have a node.
if (isset($params['node'])) {
  $node = $params['node'];
  $variables += array(
  '%uid' => $node->uid,
  '%node_url' => url('node/' . $node->nid, array('absolute' => TRUE)),
  '%node_type' => node_type_get_name($node),
  '%title' => $node->title,
  '%teaser' => $node->teaser,
  '%body' => $node->body,
 );
}
$subject = strtr($context['subject'], $variables);
$body = strtr($context['message'], $variables);
$message['subject'] .= str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $subject);
$message['body'][] = drupal_html_to_text($body);
}
```

For More details go through the [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7).